# How to make Unity3D Camera focusing on one area?

Tags: c#, unity

In my Unity3D project, I have a board created dynamically (using c#) and located on the screen as follow:

```
0 < x < 12
0 < z < 12
y = -1
```

- How can I make the camera focusing on the board and make it centered for different screen resolutions and for different platforms?

**EDIT:**

What I have tried so far

```
public class PositionCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fWidth = 9.0f;  // Desired width 

    void Start () {

        float fT = fWidth / Screen.width * Screen.height;
        fT = fT / (2.0f * Mathf.Tan (0.5f * Camera.main.fieldOfView * Mathf.Deg2Rad));
        Vector3 v3T = Camera.main.transform.position;
        v3T.z = -fT;
        v3T.y = 3f;
        transform.position = v3T;
    }
}
```

I have attached this script to my camera. Actually, it makes the board look much better but not centered on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt see EDIT.